# How to check from what path application is run?

Tags: windows, networking, batch-file, dos

For example I have entered

> netsh.exe

in command line (aka cmd.exe)

Now I would like to know which netsh.exe is being run, lets say I have **more than one netsh.exe** on my PATH (I do know that the first one in the PATH will be run, but lets say I have a **very BIG PATH** and I don't have time to search for it manually. To be fair its not always your machine you are using and **many times PATH is set by admins** and many times they are not the best).

**Is there any way in windows to find that out from command line?** I want to write a **BATCH application** that is using that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following blog post does exactly what you want: http://pankaj-k.net/weblog/2004/11/equivalent_of_which_in_windows.html

Answer (score 5):

It's a one-liner batch file:

```
@for %%e in (%PATHEXT%) do @for %%i in (%1%%e) do @if NOT "%%~$PATH:i"=="" echo %%~$PATH:i
```

Save this as whereis.cmd, then type

```
whereis netsh
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use Windows Management Instrument (WMI) to query:

```
"SELECT ExecutablePath FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name = 'netsh.exe'"
```

http://www.activexperts.com/activmonitor/windowsmanagement/wmi/samples/ WMI samples

You will need to find something suitable for your scripting

Comment: is that build in in windows? XP too?

Comment: That for sure. even win2k has it. To test it start-> run "wbemtest.exe" connect -> "root\cimv2" -> connect -> query -> <enter you query> (query language is similar to sql) -> apply

Answer (score 1):

On Windows Server (at least 2003 and 2008, dont know with 2000) you can use **where.exe**

> Where.exe /?
>   Description:
>       Displays the location of files that match the search pattern.
>       By default, the search is done along the current directory and
>       in the paths specified by the PATH environment variable.
>   ...

The first file listed is also the first file windows will use.
I use a copy on my XP workstation and it works fine too.